# PHP Code to get STRING from site and SAVE to .js file / site instead of VB.NET

Tags: php

i am programming a little bit in VB.net and ich have a code to search into a website for a string and give me the next 4 characters after the string i need... so far so good... in vb.net no Problem:

```
    Dim value As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(TextBox1.Text)
Dim wordArr As Integer = value.IndexOf("plid=")
Dim substring As String = value.Substring(wordArr + 5, 4)
substring = "var plid2 = '" & substring & "';"
```

.... and then save it to a plid.js File on my local machine

Now I want to place a cron job on to my server. I have to do this now in a PHP file......Now Question...... does anyone knows a simple PHP Way for my problem????

:-)

Comment: Sure, start with a combination of [`file_get_contents()`](https://php.net/file_get_contents), [`strpos()`](https://php.net/strpos) and [`substr()`](https://php.net/substr) and see how far that gets you.

Comment: hi... thanks... do you know some sample code? my profession is only VB.net ;-)

Comment: Thanks... i got it.... yes it was still simple... thanks for your tipps! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks to rickdenhaan..... if someone searching for such code.... here is the way which works for me:

```
    <?php
$meinString = file_get_contents('URL');
$findMich   = 'toni=';
$pos = strpos($meinString, $findMich);
$plid = "var plid2 = '" . substr($meinString, $pos + 5, 4) . "';";
$myfile = fopen("plid.js", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $plid);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```